# remove duplicates entry in vectors

Tags: c++

I am trying to add objects using class(Sample),sort my vector and after that remove duplicates entries in my vector.

my codes (this is just part of my codes in my program)

```
vector<Sample> sampleVector;
sort(sampleVector.begin(), sampleVector.end());
sampleVector.erase(std::unique(sampleVector.begin(),sampleVector.end(),sampleVector.end()));
```

but however it when I tried to run my program it shows this error.

```
Type 'std::__1::__wrap_iter<Sample *>' does not provide a call operator
```

and I realized that most likely the error is caused by this line

```
sampleVector.erase(std::unique(sampleVector.begin(),sampleVector.end(),sampleVector.end()));
```

What should I do so that I can make it work to remove duplicate entries in my vector?
thanks in advance

Another thing I have tried but it's not working.

```
bool myfunction (Sample *i,Sample *j) {
   return (i==j);
}

std::vector<Sample>::iterator it;
vector<Sample> sampleVector;
it = std::unique(sampleVector.begin(), sampleVector.end(),myfunction);   
for (it=sampleVector.begin(); it!=sampleVector.end(); ++it) {
            std::cout << *it << " "; <-- error must change it to &*it
}
```

Comment: Read carefully: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique

Comment: Alternative link, with example: [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/unique/)

Comment: @paddy so it only works with primitive data types only? like vector<int>

Comment: It will work as is (after the correction), if `Sample` provides `operator==`, or if you modify the call (as per documentation) to supply a binary predicate function.

Answer (score 2):

Misplaced parenthesis.  Correction:

```
sampleVector.erase( std::unique(sampleVector.begin(),sampleVector.end()),
                    sampleVector.end() );
```

I don't blame you for getting caught out.  C++ compiler errors are heinous.

Comment: Alright thanks. finally managed to understand the links that you psoted and got my remove for duplicates function working

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this code below

```
bool myfunction (int i, int j) {
     return (i==j);
}
std::unique (myvector.begin(), myvector.end(), myfunction);
std::cout << "myvector contains:";
for (it=myvector.begin(); it!=myvector.end(); ++it){
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: You don't have to use myfunction() as predicate

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility worth considering is that you could put the sorted elements into an `std::set`. That will retain the sorted ordering and ensure item uniqueness.

Comment: Ok.finally I managed to understand the link that @paddy has posted and I solved my problems. thanks for your suggestion and help

Comment: as well as @QuestionMarcs